# How to get socket id of a Node.js socket.io clien

Tags: node.js, socket.io, heartbeat

When i run my nodeJS code,i found some heartbeat are emitting for client with client socketid. Here is debug code -

debug - emitting heartbeat for client D2ce41SGs_Rp-qiRKndU

debug - websocket writing 2::

debug - set heartbeat timeout for client D2ce41SGs_Rp-qiRKndU

debug - got heartbeat packet

debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client D2ce41SGs_Rp-qiRKndU

debug - set heartbeat interval for client D2ce41SGs_Rp-qiRKndU

**Is there any way to get socket_id of client. In this case it is --> D2ce41SGs_Rp-qiRKndU**

Comment: what socket library are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

At least for Socket.IO 1.0+ there is an [`id` property](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/1f7da938bd69cdb6524d196fe4e71a8efdec8df1/Readme.md#socketidstring) on each socket object.